# derived invariants, perversity and modular coefficients

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, perverse-sheaves, derived-algebraic-geometry, modular-representation-theory

Let $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ a Galois cover of finite type schemes over $\mathbb{C}$ of group $\Gamma$.

Let $n$ an integer such that it is *not* prime with the order of $\Gamma$.
Then $\pi_{*}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is perverse with a $\Gamma$-action.

If I take derived invariants for $\Gamma$, is it true that the sheaf is still perverse?